# fwrite append , appending before php end

Tags: php, fwrite

i would like to store a string into a .php file,but as such , its a php script itself , in which i would like to add array(s),but so far i always append string like this

```
<?php
$.....
....
?>
```

but i would like to only add the content without opening and closing new block of code.
so to have only one opening and closing of script , thus appending before the actual end of file.
How can i efficiently move the pointer like this ?

my function so far looks like this

```
 $fw = fopen('../Resource/articlelist.php',"a");
 .....
 fwrite ($fw,$diffWrite);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP interpreter doesn't require a closing `?>` on the end of files, just omit that and you it will work the same.

---

(just to answer the title of the question)
For moving the internal pointer of the file resource, there's [fseek()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php).

```
$fd = fopen('file', 'a');
fseek($fd, -3, SEEK_END); // now the pointer is at the end -3 bytes
```

You can create a loop that reads in chunks from the end moving backwards and search for the first `?>` if you want to make this appending more robust.